# jquery how to append multiple var's to a div?

Tags: jquery, appendto

i have some var's:

```
var1 = ('1');
var2 = ('2');
var3 = ('3');
```

how to append them to a div using jquery `appendTo` ?

```
var1, var2, var3.appendTo('.div');
```

thanks

edit:

```
var1 = $('<div class="1"></div>');
var2 = $('<div class="2"></div>');
var3 = $('<div class="3"></div>');
```

i want it to look like this:

```
<div class="div">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
</div>
```

i can use:

```
var1.appendTo('.div');
var2.appendTo('.div');
var3.appendTo('.div');
```

but what if i have 15 vars??
and `append` alone doesn't do the job

Comment: What do you mean by var's and appending to div? Do you mean jquery wrapped HTML elements when you say var's?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('.div').append(var1, var2, var3)
```

whatever a var is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the append function instead:

```
    $('.div').append(var1).append(var2).append(var3);
```

Comment: i don't know if it will work as well as `appendTo`, i had some problems using `append`

Comment: is this better/worse than `$('.div').append(var1 + var2 + var3);`?

Comment: maybe you were not selecting the right div element. does it have class="div" ?

Comment: @Dutchie432 It really depends on what var1, var2 and var3 represent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div').append(var1).append(var2).append(var3)
```

Comment: is this better/worse than `$('.div').append(var1 + var2 + var3);`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> .append( content [, content ] )
>
> **content**
>
> Type: htmlString or Element or
>   Text or **Array** or jQuery

Passing array is more convenient.

```
var items = [];

for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
   items.push($('<div />', { class: i}));
}

$('.div').append(items);
```